# 2sxc: 404 Error after adding App module on the page. API is missing?

Tags: 2sxc

I have a problem when placing an App module(v 8.4.8) on a page. When I placed an App module on a page I got a pop up saying "Had an error talking to the server (status 404). if you are an advanced user you can learn more about what went wrong - discover how on 2sxc.org/help?tag=debug".
This error happens on whatever action I try to do: trying to add and app, refresh page etc. 
I checked a communication to the server using Firebug and seems that one of APIs are missing: 
~/desktopmodules/2sxc/api/view/Module/GetSelectableApps
Referer: ~/desktopmodules/tosic_sexycontent/dist/dnn/ui.html?sxcver=8.4.8.19191

Did I missed something? Should I make some configuration after SexyContent module install (v 8.4.8)?
I just checked a video by Daniel Mettler where he showed how to install a module and seems that process is simple. Nothing to worry about.
Does anybody has any idea what might went wrong here?

The same actually happens when I install and Content module: Error about missing APIs:
~/desktopmodules/2sxc/api/view/Module/GetSelectableContentTypes
~/desktopmodules/2sxc/api/view/Module/GetSelectableTemplates

Thanks a lot for your time

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that it's an issue with the dnn domain/path configuration. So basically my guess is that

1. you have multiple domains, and if this is configured incorrectly, the paths in the js-calls won't fully match the original one
2. you have sub-portal (with paths like /products/) or something, and this isn't configured correctly in dnn
3. languages in portal-paths are causing similar issues.

So please compare EXACTLY the full base path and see if that's the issue.

Comment: Thank you Daniel very much for quick response and for instructions. Problem was related to some module that was already installed on DNN 8.0.3 and has nothing to do to 2scx module.
Thanks a lot